# How to handle navigation logic in selenium web driver tests

Tags: c#, selenium, coded-ui-tests

I'm new to selenium web driver. I am trying to implement an automated suite of tests and I am following the POM (Page Object Model). My question is about page navigation. I instantiate the web driver in my actual test. Do I then tell it which URL to go to? If that's the case, then do I have to do that every time I write a test? Or is there a better way to handle navigation where perhaps the page object would have the URL in it, so I don't have to specify it on every single test. Would like to see various options and what others are doing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Only one time you need to specify that Url and one time webdriver initialization is also enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can Initialize a specific browser once like below

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

if your each pages required different URL to be executed you can choose from

```
// And now use this to visit Google
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
// Alternatively the same thing can be done like this
// driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");
```

with same driver instance. it will not open browser again.
you can write Driver initialization according to your need such as *

> AssemblyLevel/ClassLevel/TestLevel.

*

Answer (score 0):

After you instantiate your Webdriver you use the .get() method to direct your browser as to what url to go to.

You only do this when you need to go directly to a URL.
In your case I would pass the base URL in as a String that is set in your constructor. That way in your class you can simply run

```
 driver.get(baseURL);
```

Where baseURL is that predefined string that you have either passed through when creating an instance of your test class or you can hardcode in the constructor.